# SSMS: List of frequenly used queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Does anyone know if there is an add-in or if there is a place where you can save frequently used SQL queries, besides keyboard shortcuts?  I would want to save a query like this one to a "Favorites" location so I can reference it when I need it.  I would want to change the 'Where' criteria  for `c.name LIKE '%%'`.  Which is why keyboard shortcuts wouldn't work.

PS: I don't have SA or admin rights on my DB.

```
SELECT 
t.name AS table_name, 
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name, 
c.name AS column_name 
FROM 
sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE 
c.name LIKE '%%' 
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Comment: ssms allows you to save queries to your local file system.  It's on the main menu under File.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Template Explorer (keyboard Shortcut is Ctrl + Alt+ T)
In Template explorer right-click to create new Template and Edit it to type in your query. For each query, you can select it by double-clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: You need template explorer, as written above. Addition: You can add your own templates using following path schema:

C:\Users\WIN_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates\Sql\GROUP\TEMPLATE NAME.sql

If you have some very-frequently used scripts and want to have them on fingertips you might find this feature useful:
http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-autoreplacements
[image: SSMSBoost auto-replacements]

"Autoreplacements" allow to define some snippet, that will be inserted after you type token and press space/enter/tab. This is frature of SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS, which I develop.